# check when WebView has completely loaded including url redirection

Tags: android, webview

Suppose there is a website which on loading automatically redirects to another url somewhat like this `http://mydomain.com/ -> http://mydomain.com/index.html`.

Now whenever `WebView.loadURL("http://mydomain.com/")` is called `onPageFinished()` obviously is loaded twice. I want to be able to run my code after all of the loading is done including the automatic redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page has finished loading, check if the HTTP Response code was 200 OK. If it is a redirect, it will be a 301 or 303. Depending upon that you can ignore the onPageFinished() listener.